# how to avoid horizontal scrolling in jquery mobile of page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

can you please tell me how to avoid horizontal scrolling in query mobile?
Actually my page is able to horizontally..[image]

I need to remove horizontal scrolling only user scroll vertically which is working..?

here is my code..

```
<div data-role="page" id="realTimeScreen" > 
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">

        <h1 class="ui-title"  id="heading" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 20px;" ></h1>
        <div class="ui-btn-right" id="addbuttons" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <a ><img src="img/Follow-Realtime.png" class="follow_h"id=""/></a>
            <a><img src="img/Stop-Realtime.png" id="" class="stop_h"/></a>
            <a><img src="img/Email-Document.png" id="" class="email_h"/></a>
            <a><img src="img/search.png" id="" class="search_h" /></a>
            <a><img src="img/zoom-in.png" id="" class ="zoomIn_h"/></a>
            <a><img src="img/Export-Realtime.png" id="" class="exportRealTime_h"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="searchContend_h" style="display: none">

      <div class="ui-grid-c">
      <div class="ui-block-a"  style="width: 30%;" >
        <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text" autocorrect="off" class="searchbox">     
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false"  data-inline="true"  class="search">Search</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-c" style="margin-left: 5px;">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false"  data-inline="true"  id="next" class="searchNext" disabled>Next</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-d" style="margin-left: 30px;">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" data-inline="true" id="prev"  class="searchPrev" disabled>Previous</a>
    </div>

</div>


</div>

                          <!--div data-role="fieldcontain">

                            <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text"  class="textSearchvalue_h">
                              <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false"  data-inline="true" class="searchButtonClickText_h" >Search</a>
                             <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false"  data-inline="true" class="next_h">Next</a>
                             <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" data-inline="true" class="previous_h">Previous</a>
                         </div--> 
                         <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="sliderContend_h" style="display: none; padding-top:10px;">

                             <input type="range" name="slider-2" id="slider-2" value="15" min="15" max="25"  class="slider_h" data-highlight="true" />

                         </div>

                         <div data-role="content" data-theme="d">


                            <div id="realTimeContents" class="realtimeContend_h">

                            </div>
                          <div class="cursor" style="font-size:23px;">|</div>
                        </div>






</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `overflow-y: hidden`?

Comment: Do you have a viewport meta tag?  Please paste the contents of the `head` tag on your page, and any CSS affecting the `body`, `html`, and main container element.

Comment: i tried but not able to solve..!!